# Android Eclipse String Txt + Edittext + String Txt = Crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, browser

My App Chashs.

here is the code where goes wrong!

```
    public void wbsuche(View view) {
    String url = "http://www.xxxxx.de/s/?tag=xxxxx&link_code=wsw&_encoding=UTF-8&search-alias=aps&field-keywords=";
    String zrlll = "&Submit.x=-89&Submit.y=-23&Submit=Go";
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String cstrsk = et.getText().toString().trim();
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.suche_wbv);
    setContentView(R.layout.suche_wb);
    wv.loadUrl(url + cstrsk + zrlll);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new wb_c_suche());
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ladedaten1);
    TV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imgbg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgimg);
    imgbg1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me

Comment: Please post your log cat

Comment: i get no chrash reports on my Devise sry

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely plug in your device and look at the logcat output.  I know you said you don't get crash reports on your device, but you actually do.  It's critical that you have a way to see stack traces.

That being said, are you setting the content view before calling `findViewById()`?  If not, your activity doesn't have a view hierarchy to traverse, and your WebView object will be null on this line:

> WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.suche_wbv);

When you try to call `loadUrl()` on that web view, you'll crash with a null pointer exception.

Comment: Okay if that is why the error is not just there? in the app, there are a pair of the same functions that I built the same on and they work.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if your WebView is coming from suche_wb.xml file? If so then you have to put `setContentView(R.layout.suche_wb)` before doing `wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.suche_wbv)`. Check if this works.

Update:

Please put your `setContentView(R.layout.suche_wb)` before getting `findViewById` of your **EditText** if EditText is also coming from *suche_wb.xml*. See what happens.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is `yourEditText.getText().toString().trim();`
trim() method deletes the spaces from the beginning or end of the string. What about the spaces on the other characters?